# Обработать строку в MYSQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

mySQL v5.7.26. Функции REGEXP_REPLACE() в этой версии к сожалению нет.

Задача написать функцию обработки строки (UTF8) по следующим правилам:

1. Перевести строку в нижний регистр
2. Заменить все символы, кроме [a-zа-я0-9] пробелами
3. Удалить двойные пробелы и пробелы в начале, конце строки.

Можно ли это сделать в mySQL v5.7.26?

Comment: Можно. Итерационая UDF. Имеющихся строковых функций вполне достаточно.

Comment: с 1ым и 3им пунктом более менее ясно. А вот как реализовать 2ой имеющимися функциями?

Comment: Ну вариантов два. Первый - влоб, перебирать по одной букве, копируя в переменную назначения только валидные символы. Второй - искать готовую UDF с регэкспами для 5.7, подключать и использовать.